# Send a fancy mail with PHPMailer from Beefree

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send an email with PHPMailer. The mail is a HTML made up mail with Beefree. First the whole email was a PHP variable, but then I get the email with the first part repeated. I think this is a result of having a head in the body, but I'm not sure.

To clear this out the mail I want to send is this (with fancy lay-out):

```
[image]
Hello John,

How are you?

Best regards!
```

But it is send like this:

```
[image]
Hello $name,

[image]
Hello $name,

<div style="Margin: 0 auto;min-width: 320px;max-width: 600px;ov
```

Now I saved my mail as beefree.php. It is possible to send it like this:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('beefree.php'));
```

The file is now send with a correct lay-out, but with variables, like 'Hello $name'.

To solve this I can do this:

```
ob_start();
include 'beefree.php'; //execute the file as php
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

and send it like this:

```
$mail->msgHTML($body);
```

Then the variables are inserted, I see the real name, but the email is like the second mail-example, except the real name is visible. The problem is why it has repeated parts and not the whole email. How can I send the mail like in the file_get_contents, but with the correct variables?

Comment: What is content of 'beefree.php'

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, you see the real name (in `$body`?), but  the email (from `$body`?) shows the original php code? That's not possible.

Comment: Check what's in the parsed template string - look at what's in `$body` before you pass it to `msgHTML` and what's in `$mail->Body` afterwards. You may not beed to use `msgHTML` - setting `Body` explicitly may be more appropriate - `msgHTML` does other things that you may not want.

Comment: The content of beefree.php is: https://pastebin.com/f5FF1ekf

The real name is really in the second example, I meant it was still repeating and not showing the whole mail. I will edit the question.

Comment: With the var_dump I found out that my body is correct, but after I send it with a POST to another page (the page with the mailer) then it is going wrong. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Solved! Use http_build_query(); with the cURL!